# While foreach loop returns random list of numbers

Tags: php, mysqli

I have several columns I am wanting to turn into a table with the value as the row it pertains to. EXAMPLE:

In my table I have 4 columns named `column1 column2 column3 column4`. Those columns only have 1 row that will be found. Such as `SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM operations WHERE active = '1'` 

The row it finds looks something like this (with columns)

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4
_____________________________________
3456    | 265     | 795     | 425
```

I want it to display a table that looks like:

```
column1 | 3456
column2 | 265
column3 | 795
column4 | 425
```

The following script works, but it also displays a random list of numbers I believe that are associated with the columns somehow.

```
function oreAmount() {
        $sql = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT `column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`column4` FROM operations WHERE active = '1'");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
            foreach ($row as $key => $var) {
                echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$var</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
```

This function displays the following:

```
0       | 3456
column1 | 3456
1       | 265
column2 | 265
2       | 795
column3 | 795
3       | 425
column4 | 425
```

I'm not sure why or where the numbers are coming from and I need them removed.

Comment: use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Use your `foreach` loop outside the `while` loop, you will get dubble result as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`.

**Explanation**

`mysqli_fetch_array` is always return result with two kind of indexing.

1. MYSQLI_NUM (indexing in numeric keys)
2. MYSQLI_ASSOC (indexing in associate names)

So either pass param which kind of indexing you want to retrieve your results like

`mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)`.

or simple use

`mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Accepted as answer because it was the most detailed. Thank you, it gave me a full understanding of what indexes `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Glad to know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)
```

This way you will only get the column names

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` in place of `mysqli_fetch_array`

It will fetch a result row as an associative array

[Full description here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)